# i want to know how the static properties work in c# and i don't get the meaning of 'Instance._input;

Tags: c#

I don't get the meaning of 'Instance._input;

1.What is the relationship between the properties 'Instance' and the instance '_input"? is it related to static?

2.I don't understand that why 'Instance" comes earlier then _input (Instance._input;)

I am sorry asking for easy question

```
public class managers : MonoBehaviour
{

    static managers s_instance; // 유일한 매니저를 갖고온다

    public static managers Instance
    {
        get { return s_instance; }
    }

    InputManager _input = new InputManager();

    public static InputManager Input
    {
        get { return Instance._input; } 
    }
```

Comment: You should also show the part where s_instance is set. Then someone has a complete picture to describe how the singleton pattern with a static instance works in your case.

Answer (score 0):

The `Instance` is a static property of class `managers`, it returns `s_instance` static variable of class `managers`.

Therefore `Instance._input` will return the instance variable `_input` of type `InputManager` of static variable `Instance` of type `managers`.

The naming conventions of your provided code could cause confusions. Consider this code:

```
public class Manager : MonoBehavior {
    static Manager staticManager;
    
    public InputManager inputManager = new InputManager();

    public static Manager GetStaticManager() { return staticManager;}

    public static InputManager GetInputManagerOfStaticManager() { return GetStaticManager().inputManager; }
}
```

When you declare something `static`, its on class scope. All objects created from the same class shared the same static copy. You access them as `Manager.GetStaticManager()`. Calling `Manager.inputManager` will fail.

On the other hand, non-static member is on object/instance scope. You need to create that object first:

```
var manager = new Manager();
var myInputManager = manager.inputManager;
```